# find biggest cross shape in array of coordinate

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

[please see this image before reading :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91v97.jpg)

finding a centroid coordinate based on the biggest multiply of left/right/top/down side

below code is working but has no end with bigger array.
how can i optimize this:

(if numpy matters , i am passing region to find_centroid with `region=region_coordinates.tolist()`)

```
def find_centroid(region):
    centroid = region[0]
    coord_weight = 0
    for coord in region:
        new_coord_weight = weight_calc(region, coord, -1, 0)*weight_calc(
            region, coord, 1, 0)*weight_calc(region, coord, 0, -1)*weight_calc(region, coord, 0, 1)
        if new_coord_weight > coord_weight:
            coord_weight = new_coord_weight
            centroid = coord
    return centroid

def weight_calc(region, coord, xinc, yinc):
    weight = 1
    x = coord[0] 
    y = coord[1] 
    while(True):
        if [x, y] in region:
            weight += 1
            x += xinc
            y += yinc
        else:
            break
    return weight
```

and for a test :

```
array_test = ([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 0], [2, 0], [3, 2]])
print(find_centroid(array_test))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else who need a better(may be perfect)answer is using an small shape passed through `erosion` Over the array in a `while` loop which remove a border until find:
-one cross : the center coordinates
-many cross : compare for best one separately

Answer (score 1):

## ***No*** infinite loop explained

This part of your code will get you stuck in an infinite loop **if region is a numpy array**:

```
while True:
    if [x, y] in region:
    ...
```

That's because, when used on arrays, the operator `in` will return True if any of the element of the list matches any of the array's sublist elements.

Instead, you can use python's `any` and `all` methods :

```
if (np.array(region)==[x,y]).all(axis=1).any(axis=0):
```

1. The `all(axis=1)` will check for every sublist if both values are equal, in the correct order.
2. We got an array of boolean. If any boolean is True, then there is at least one match.

Casting any of both lists into a numpy array is enough to make this test possible.

### But it will work if...

If both elements are lists, the *in* operator will work as expected, but in that case you should make sure that **region and each of its sublist are all list**, not a numpy array. Casting it won't work. Here is why :

```
import numpy as np
array_test = [[0, 0], [1, 0]]
print([1,1] in array_test) # prints False, as expected

# numpy always compares element-wise, when both elements have the same length
print([1,1] == np.array([1,0])) # Prints [True, False]
print(np.array([1,1]) == np.array([1,0]))  # [Line 6] Prints [True, False]
# Errors when ambiguous "in"
print([1,1] == np.array(array_test)) # Prints [[False False] [ True False]]
print([1,1] in np.array(array_test)) # Prints true as explained, because we have at least one True 

print([1,1] in list(np.array(array_test))) #Error because numpy doesn't know how to evaluate the result at line 6
```

## Another version

Here is my way of doing this. There might be better ways, it's just my two cents.

### Pre-filtering the potential centroids

First, I'd compose all possible intersections (I'll call them "centers" from now) in the region. So first, I would count every x coordinate and y coordinate. To make it easy, I will use numpy.

```
import numpy as np
# We count every x values. We keep those that are present at least twice. 
x_counts = dict(zip(*np.unique(array_test[:,0], return_counts=True)))
y_counts = dict(zip(*np.unique(array_test[:,1], return_counts=True)))
# If an x is present once, then there cannot be any center in this column.
x_inter = [coord  for coord, count in x_counts.items() if count>=2]
# Same with y and rows.
y_inter = [coord  for coord, count in y_counts.items() if count>=2]
# Next, we create all combinations of (x, y)
# an filter in the combinations present in our region.
possible_centroids = np.array([(x,y) for x,y in product(x_inter, y_inter)
        if (array_test==np.array([x,y])).all(axis=1).any())
```

### Measuring arm lengths

To calculate the power of our centers, we first use a function to measure the arm length. Let's make it a bit parametrable, with a `direction`argument.

```
# Since we are in 2D and we have no diagonal, there are four possible directions.
directions = np.array([[0,1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0]])

def get_arm_length(center, direction):
    position = center+direction # going one step in the direction
    # We keep track of the length in the direction. 
    length = 0
    # adding 1 as long as the next step in direction is in region
    while (region==position).all(axis=1).any():
        position += direction
        length+=1
    return length
```

### Measuring every potential centroid

Now we can test the four directions, for each of our potential centroids (previously selected) and keeping the best one along the way.

```
best_center=(0,[-1, -1]) # => (power, center_coords)
for center in centers:
    # Setting to 1, which is the identity element of the product (x * 1 == x)
    power = 1
    for direction in directions:
        # We multiply by the power along the four axes.
        power *= get_arm_length(center, direction)
    # if a more powerful one is found, we store it power and coords.
    if power > best_center[0]:
        best_center = power, center
# At this point, we found most powerful center, which is our centroid.
```

## Putting it all together

Here is the full code.

```
def find_centroid2(region):    
   
    region = np.array(region)

    # Directions:
    directions = np.array([[0,1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0]])

    def get_arm_length(center, direction):
        position = center+direction
        length = 1
        while (region==position).all(axis=1).any(axis=0):
            position+= direction
            length+=1
        return length

    # Intersections: 
    x_counts = dict(zip(*np.unique(region[:,0], return_counts=True))) 
    y_counts = dict(zip(*np.unique(region[:,1], return_counts=True)))
    x_inter = [coord  for coord, count in x_counts.items() if count>=2]
    y_inter = [coord  for coord, count in y_counts.items() if count>=2]
    centers = np.array([(x,y) for x,y in product(x_inter, y_inter) if (region==np.array([x,y])).all(axis=1).any()])
    # Measuring each center's "power":
    best_center=(0,[-1, -1]) # => (power, center_coords)
    for center in centers:
        power = 1
        for direction in directions:
            power *= get_arm_length(center, direction)
        if power > best_center[0]:
            best_center = power, center
    return best_center[1]
```

## An optimisation's optimisation

Instead of testing all virtual centers to keep the ones that belong to our region, we can instead filter our region and keep the cells that have a coordinate counted twice or more.

```
def find_centroid3(region):    

    region = np.array(region)

    # Directions:
    directions = np.array([[0,1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0]])

    def get_arm_length(center, direction):
        position = center+direction
        length = 1
        while (region==position).all(axis=1).any(axis=0):
            position+= direction
            length+=1
        return length

    # Intersections: 
    # It's better to filter the cells instead of computing and testing all combinations
    x_counts = [x[0] for x in zip(*np.unique(region[:,0], return_counts=True)) if x[1]>=2]
    y_counts = [y[0] for y in zip(*np.unique(region[:,1], return_counts=True)) if y[1]>=2]
    centers = [[x,y] for x,y in region if x in x_counts or y in y_counts]

    # Measuring each center's "power":
    best_center=(0,[-1, -1]) # => (power, center_coords)
    for center in centers:
        power = 1
        for direction in directions:
            power *= get_arm_length(center, direction)
        if power > best_center[0]:
            best_center = power, center
    return best_center[1]
```

## Comparing V2

The random region preparation, with a lot of cells.

```
# Keeping the grid fairly big and filled
# 150*150 grid (22'500 cells) with 15'000 filled cells max.
array_test = np.random.randint(15, size=(150, 2)) # => len = 15'000
# Getting rid of duplicates, else they will mess with the counting.
# Assuming your own grids also don't have any
new_array = [list(array_test[0])]
for elem in array_test[1:]:
    if (elem != np.array(new_array)).any(axis=1).all():
        new_array.append(elem)
array_test = np.array(new_array) # => len = 10'959, all are unique cells
```

Results:

```
find_centroid(array_test) # Original version. Result = [64 127]
# 16 s ± 117 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
find_centroid(array_test) # Proposed version 1. result = [61 127]
# 13.1 s ± 87.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
find_centroid3(array_test) # Proposed version 2. Result = [61, 127]
# 9.49 s ± 47.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I tried several grid sizes, keeping it half filled at max.

[image: Performance comparison V2]

### Comparing V1

**[Obsolete]**

Your original code (corrected for dealing with the infinite loop):

```
%%timeit
find_centroid(array_test) # Result => array([73, 16])
# 21.4 s ± 397 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The proposed code:

```
%%timeit
find_centroid2(array_test) # Result => array([73, 16])
# 17.2 s ± 76.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

That's not a tremendous optimisation, but that's an optimization anyways.
Maybe some other reviews and other ideas can make it better.

I tried several grid sizes, keeping it half filled at max.

[image: Performance comparison]

Comment: Wow . Thanks for this teacher guide ;) really glad to see such descriptions. let me replace yours in my code and i will come to answer.

Comment: Well I have a mistake already about the "in" operator. The case I was discribing was when using "in" on a numpy array, not on a python list. `[1,2] in np.array([[1,0],[0,0]])`will return `True`, for example. But `[1,2] in [[1,0],0,2]]` will return `False`. Let me correct that.

Comment: I forgot an old variable name. It's corrected, sorry about that! That's what happens when programming in notebooks.

Comment: as same as your graph shows it is faster. still too long calculation with bigger region, and i think the problem is with doing calculation for all 'centers' , if we do calculation only once after sorting the region by same x or y values or pick the most occurrence by built in function like most_common.am i right?

Comment: Answering you, I came to an even better solution. Sorting would be a great idea in heuristic approach. But if we want to be 100% sure that we found the centroid, sorting won't help us. As an example, `7*5*7*5` is smaller than `6*6*6*6`. It would have been a great optimisation if we were asked to find the centroid while given its weight beforehand. As for Counter, it's a clever and simpler idea but it seems about 4 times slower than the dict(zip(*unique)) method.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the better solution. It's obviously better to check if each cell of the region is a center (still using the same idea of pre-filtering after counting Xs and Ys) than checking if a virtual center is inside the region.